# Confirmation of messages between nodes in dynamic shovelling

Tags: rabbitmq

I know Rabbit MQ supports the mechanism of Publisher Confirms – the broker's acknowledgements to publishers. The documentation states the broker confirms messages as it handles them by sending a basic.ack on a channel that was set in “confirm mode”. This communication is between a broker and a publisher client.

Let’s assume that I have a main node A and a secondary B in another data center and that dynamic shovelling is set from A to B. According to the documentation “ack-mode” determines how the shovel acknowledges messages. If set to on “on-confirm” messages are acknowledge to the source broker (A) after they have been confirmed by the destination (broker B).

I’d like to ask whether these two mechanisms are connected (or whether they can be). When a client connected to node A receives a confirmation, does that mean that the message has been published to node B too (if ack-mode=on-confirm)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No these are not connected , in case of Dynamic Shovels what comes into picture is **ack-mode** which is one of the configuration parameter of the shovel. It can take three possible values and these are

> - on-confirm
> - on-publish
> - no-ack

This is how it works.

**ack-mode** Determines how the shovel should acknowledge messages. If set to `on-confirm` (the default), messages are acknowledged to the source broker after they have been confirmed by the destination. This handles network errors and broker failures without losing messages, and is the slowest option.

If set to `on-publish`, messages are acknowledged to the source broker after they have been published at the destination. This handles network errors without losing messages, but may lose messages in the event of broker failures.

If set to `no-ack`, message acknowledgements are not used. This is the fastest option, but may lose messages in the event of network or broker failures.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If these two mechanisms are not related - if there any guarantee that if I connect to primary node A (which is shovelled to secondary B) and publish a message and then get a confirmation but then node A dies before having moved it to node B. At that point if I switch to B - my message won't be there.